# C#.NET MVC Ajax Form Submission

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Feel like I'm missing something simple here - When I submit this form it takes me to a white page with my encoded JSON model, rather than staying on the page I was on.

Form in a partial view, loaded on every page:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Inquiry", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "success" }))
```

And my actions:

```
    public ActionResult Inquiry()
    {
        return PartialView("_Inquiry",new Inquiry());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Inquiry(Inquiry model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Inquiries.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Json(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have referenced the following script in your page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It is what makes the `Ajax.*` helpers work.

Comment: I totally did!

...before my jQuery reference.

Tired programming is a bad idea.  Thank you, will accept as answer in the morning (stupid lockout)

Comment: Yeap, it should be added after jquery.

Comment: How to make that submit page blank to add another record( once one record is submitted)???